# $E(|X_n|) = O(a_n) \implies X_n = O_p(a_n) $? Need help with proof

Tags: probability, random-variables, asymptotics

Let $X_1, X_2$,... be a sequence of RV, and $a_1, a_2$,... be a sequence of non-negative and non-stochastic numbers. Show if $E(|X_n|) = O(a_n)$ then $X_n = O_p(a_n)$.

My attempt:

$|E(|X_n|)|\leq M*a_n$ for large $n$.
Rewriting as $\frac{E(|X_n|)}{a_n} \leq M$

I think I should proceed using Markov's inequality: $1 \geq \frac{E(|X_n|)}{M*a_n} \geq P(\frac{|X_n|}{a_n}\geq M)$. Should I be focusing on limit M to $\infty$ such that $\frac{E(|X_n|)}{M*a_n}$ goes to 0? I think that would squeeze the rhs of the equation and show $|X_n| = O_p(a_n)$, but I'm not confident in my understanding of these concepts.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by $O_p(a_n)$?

Comment: $O_p(a_n)$: if for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $n=1,2,...$ there exists $B_{\epsilon}$ such that $P(\frac{|X_n|}{a_n}>B_{\epsilon})< \epsilon$

Comment: @ficknergs Do you need further explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x>0$, and any $n$, Markov inequality yilds 
$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{|X_n|}{a_n}>x\right)\leq \frac{\frac{\mathbb E(|X_n|)}{a_n} }{x} \leq \frac{M}{x} \to 0 \ \text{ as } x\to \infty.$$
Therefore for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can take $x$ large enough such that $\frac{M}{x}<\varepsilon$. And then put $B_\varepsilon=x$.

Comment: $P(\lvert X_n\rvert/a_n>x)\leq M/x, \quad \forall x>0$ and for some $M>0$ is sufficient for $X_n=O_p(a_n)$.

Comment: @CelineHarumi Exactly this is written in the answer